# Add click event listener on angular as listener of all the document

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I have a kind of side element that I want to hide when the part outside of the element is clicked, but I don't know how to implement it on typescript, I know that I could do this using jquery, but I am not allow to use it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

finally found how to made it

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      alert(event.target)    
    });
  }
```

this function adds the event, but it must be inside the `ngAfterViewInit` and not in the `onInit` function